# Перестановка нечетных и отрицательных элементов столбцов

Tags: c, массивы

Не переставляет столбцы. Сама задача:Характеристикой столбца целочисленной матрицы назовем сумму модулей его отрицательных
нечетных элементов. Переставляя столбцы заданной матрицы, расположить их в соответствии с
ростом характеристик. В чем ошибка, сам код:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>



int main()
{
    int M, N;
    
    printf("ryad pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &M);
    printf("stob pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    int** mas = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    }

    

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mas[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("vasha matrica\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ", mas[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            if ((mas[i][j] < 0) && (mas[i][j] % 2 != 0))
            {
                sum1 += abs(mas[i][j]);
            }
            if (mas[i][j + 1] < 0 && abs(mas[i][j + 1]) % 2 == 1)
            {

                sum2 += abs(mas[i][j + 1]);
            }
        }
        if (sum1 < sum2)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                
                int tmp = mas[i][j];
                mas[i][j] = mas[i][j + 1];
                mas[i][j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ", mas[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Чему у тебя равно `j` на момент перестановки столбцов? Оно у тебя больше `М` после прохода цикла.

Comment: а запись "int j=0", не обнуляет?

Comment: Это в цикле. После выхода из цикла этой переменной уже нет.  Её область видимости закончилась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы делаете только один проход пузырьковой сортировки. Он должен привести к тому, что столбец с наименьшей характеристикой встанет на последнее место. Но остальные тоже надо отсортировать, для этого нужен двойной цикл

```
int main()
{
    int M, N;

    printf("ryad pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &M);
    printf("stob pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    int** mas = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            //printf("arrayl (%d)(%d) = ", i, j);
            mas[i][j] = (rand() % 30) - 15;
        }
    }

    printf("vasha matrica\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ", mas[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int k = N-1; k >=0 ; k--)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < k; c++)
        {
            int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

            for (int r = 0; r < M; r++)
            {
                if ((mas[r][c] < 0) && (mas[r][c] % 2 != 0))
                {
                    sum1 += abs(mas[r][c]);
                }
                if (mas[r][c + 1] < 0 && abs(mas[r][c + 1]) % 2 == 1)
                {

                    sum2 += abs(mas[r][c + 1]);
                }
            }
            if (sum1 > sum2)
            {

                for (int r = 0; r < M; r++)
                {
                    int tmp = mas[r][c];
                    mas[r][c] = mas[r][c + 1];
                    mas[r][c + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    printf("---------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d ", mas[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Результат:

```
ryad pls:5
stob pls:5
vasha matrica
   -4     2   -11    -5    14
  -11     3     3     7    -1
  -10   -10   -14    12   -14
   -4    10   -13    12    -9
    6     9   -13   -12     7
---------
    2    -5    14    -4   -11
    3     7    -1   -11     3
  -10    12   -14   -10   -14
   10    12    -9    -4   -13
    9   -12     7     6   -13
```

Comment: так у меня и двойной цикл, нет?

Comment: Двойной цикл по столбцам должен быть, а внутри  их уже циклы по строкам для сравнения и обмена. Добавьте внешний цикл по k  до N, а в вашем замените предел на k

Comment: все равно не пашет, он меняет 1 раз столбцы  и все

Comment: Ну хоть бы код в компилируемом состоянии сделали. Привёл рабочий код.

Comment: ну я так же и сделал. оказывается нужно было место abs(mas[r][c + 1]) % 2 == 1, писать (r+1) % 2 !=0, до меня только щас дошло, все-равно спасибо

Comment: Вы, между прочим, получили ответы на все свои три вопроса, но ни одного ответа не приняли. Знаете, как это делается? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: не знал, поставил. я всегда тыкал на стрелочку